# Printing Multiple Pages per Sheet

Tags: c#, printing

I am trying to figure out how to print multiple copies of a page per sheet when printing a document. For example, in Microsoft Publisher, if I have a document that is 8.5"x5.5" I can set Publisher to print multiple copies with 2 pages per sheet and you will see two of the documents on one 8.5"x11" page.

Does anyone know how to do this? I have looked at [this](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/wordsnet/How+to++print+multiple+pages+on+one+sheet) which is also referenced on the MSDN forums [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/90e26033-eb5d-4460-ad51-75629724a460), but unless I am using the Aspose.Words Document object, the example isn't really helpful. Any help would be appreciated.